# Migrate SQL Server Express database to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-express, migrate

I created an ASP.Net MVC 2 project, but I want it to use a SQL Server 2005 database instead of the express version. Is there a way to force VS 2010 to create the database in SQL 2005, or at least migrate the schema to the new database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this will help you out: [Setting up SQL Server with ASP.NET MVC](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/WebDev/ServerProgramming/ASPNET/setting-up-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc)